# Why use main() when you can use static{}?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

What makes `public static void main(String args[]) {}` be the convention to test code instead of simply `static {}`?

```
class Test {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("testing");
    }
}
```

It seemingly has the same capabilities, you can instantiate owner class, use its methods, another classes, even send output as well:

```
class Test {  
    static {
        System.out.println("testing");
    }
}
```

Is there a standard reason to not use the small `static {}` to run your average test? Can I take it just as my choice/preference safely?

In other words, I'd like to find a case where you put a code in one that you couldn't (or shouldn't) put in another, that it wouldn't run or give unexpected result, etc.

Comment: Why use `static{}` when you can use `main()`? and get command-line arguments? and the ability to throw exceptions? and the ability to use `java -jar`?

Comment: Same reason you don't use constructors instead of methods, and exceptions instead of return values - it makes it *really hard to understand how your program is supposed to work*

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the most prominent reason not to use `static {}` for such things is that you have little control over when it runs. `static {}` blocks run "when the class is initialized", which means at least four (watch out for the Spanish inquisition) detrimental things for this purpose:

- It does not necessarily happen just because the class is *loaded*.
- It does, on the other hand, happen just because you want an instance of the class or reference a static field from some other class, which is the main reason why you don't really want to put code with wide-ranging side-effects in `static {}` blocks.
- It is also not guaranteed to *not* happen for such simple reasons as the Jar file being on your classpath. JVMs are free to run `static {}` blocks whenever they feel like it, as long as it is before any static references from the class from other code is made. "Before" could mean "at VM startup".
- No VM implementation has any invocation arguments to run such code for you on request.

The purpose of `static {}` blocks is to initialize static class data (in possibly quite complex ways, of course), and from the preceding points you may be able to see why it's not particularly useful for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

In java every application requires a main method which will be the entry point of the application. The main method required has the signature as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

The difference between this method and the other one you suggested (besides the fact that your application needs a main method with this signature as an entry point) is that this is a method and takes the "String[] args" parameter. This parameter is where your arguments would go when running a program from the console.

Every java application can be run from the console and therefore it makes sense for every application to have a standard entry point method which will be able to take any special arguments.

Your static {} block is not necessarily a method or a function that can be called and therefore it can not be used as a entry point into your application. It takes no parameters and you have no control over when its code block will be run.